# SharePoint Property Window shows multiple save buttons

Tags: list-form-web-part

When I open the property window of my document, SharePoint 2010 shows two or more save buttons  - see picture the image below:

[image]

In my Library I activated version control and the user must check out the content.

Why is this?

Edit: 
I must fix this with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had found a solution and it works :)

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/programmatically-update-the-sharepoint-web-part-properties-on-site-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the form in SharePoint Designer? it looks like you have two list form web parts on the page.

Comment: I do not edit the form in SharePoint Designer.
Is it posible to delete the webpart with visual Studio?

Comment: You can delete it with SharePoint Designer

Comment: i know, but i must delete the webpart with c#